# Finding the equation of motion regarding a block pulling a uniform disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

My problem is finding the equation of motion for the block. Using Newton's Second Law, I did:
$$4g-T-R=4\frac{dw}{dt}$$
But the mark scheme says:
$$4g-T-R=0.2*4\frac{dw}{dt}$$
And I don't understand why the radius has anything to do with this. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Consider the Angular Momentum.

Comment: But that doesn't have to do with the second law, right?

Comment: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Newton_s_Second_Law_Rotations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{equation} 
\begin{cases}
Mg - T - R = Ma \\
Tr = I\alpha
\end{cases}\end{equation}$

First equation from Secondo Law of Dynamics, second equation is $\sum M_i = I \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$ (Euler's second Law).
Since $I = Mr^2/2$, and $\alpha r = a$(then $\alpha = \frac{d\omega}{dt} \Leftarrow a = r\frac{d\omega}{dt}$, that is your error!) because the string is running with same velocity of the side of your  disk, you obtain

$\begin{equation} 
\begin{cases}
T = M(g - a) - R  \\
Mgr - Mar - Rr = Mr/2(r\alpha)  = Mra/2
\end{cases}\end{equation}$

$Mg - Ma - R = Ma/2$

$a = 2\frac{g - R/M}{3}$

$\alpha = 2\frac{g - R/M}{3r}$

from $\alpha= \frac{\omega^2}{2\theta}$ you obtain the needed value of $\alpha$, substiting in the previous equation you get $T$ and $R$.